Re-enabling static HTML in a PHP tree
We have an (almost) entirely PHP tree where the top level .htaccess does this:
RemoveHandler .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

Then in a single subdirectory, we just want static pages.  I tried this in a .htaccess for that directory:
php_flag engine off
RemoveHandler .html
AddHandler default-handler .html

This does not work; you end up just downloading the .html; unless I also add:
AddType text/html .html

My question is why?  (I hate just mashing code until it works, I want it to make sense.)  My understanding is that Types and Handlers are separate.  Removing a Handler shouldn't remove a Type.  The Type should still exist.  So just reassigning the default-handler to .html should make static pages work again.  But it doesn't.
Please explain where I've gone wrong.  (A valid answer could be that my initial configuration is wrong, but know that if that's the case, there may not be anything I can do about that, because of legacy code and organizational hierarchy and who owns what.  EDITING TO ADD: A better answer would explain how to override the top level without dealing with the bureaucracy I'd need to to through to fix the top level, which oversees a ton of existing content, and therefore can't be changed without extensive documentation and testing.)

The RemoveHandler pairs with AddHandler, but you have modified it with AddType at the parent directory, instead. The RemoveHandler does not remove the type (like RemoveType would), but as there is no handler for application/x-httpd-php anymore, it is treated as a file download.
Reading the documentation is a good option for mashing code until it works. Here, everything is explained in the Apache Module mod_mime documentation.

I guess I as not clear.  i was trying to say that the original top level configuration may well be wrong but may be hard for me to change.  if you want more details, then because there is a ton of existing content operating under that legacy top level .htaccess, I would have to go through a complex bureaucratic procedure to fix that, getting an change request, and testing it for weeks, and... it's not worth the time and effort.

This seems clear: you modify a type and you need to modify it again, back to text/html.
